# I have a select class that is targeting both select inputs on a page but i only want it to target the one in the footer

Tags: html, css, class

```
   <?php
        /**
         * @var Multisite_Block_Region $this
         * @var Mage_Core_Model_Website $website
         */
        $websites = $this->getWebsites();
    ?>
    <div class="select">
        <span><?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/store_label'); ?></span>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($websites as $website): ?>
                <?php
                    $defaultStore = $website->getDefaultStore();
                    $code = Mage::getStoreConfig(Local_RegionRedirect_Helper_Data::XPATH_SYSTEM_CONFIG_COUNTRY, $defaultStore);
                ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('regionredirect/index/set', array('_query' => array('code' => $code))) ?>">
                        <?php echo $website->getDefaultStore()->getConfig('general/store_information/store_label'); ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>


This is the only select box I want to target:

    <div class="region">
                    <div class="select">
            <ul style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;">
                                    <li>
                    <a href="http://local/regionredirect/index/set/?code=AU">
                        Australia (AUD $)                </a>
                </li>
                                    <li>
                    <a href="http://local/regionredirect/index/set/?code=CA">
                        Canada (CA $)                </a>
                </li>
                                    <li>
                    <a href="http://local/regionredirect/index/set/?code=ML">
                        Europe (€)                </a>
                </li>
                                    <li>
                    <a href="http://local/regionredirect/index/set/?code=US">
                        USA ($)                </a>
                </li>
                                    <li>
                    <a href="http://local/regionredirect/index/set/?code=JP">
                        Japan (¥)                </a>
                </li>
                                    <li class="last">
                    <a href="http://local/regionredirect/index/set/?code=GB">
                        UK (£)                </a>
                </li>
                </ul>
    </div>
                                </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried changing the class name but it breaks... i also tried to remove it and specifically put it in the span to try and only target the footer location. Neither worked.

Header is broken:

[image]

Footer is fine:

[image]

I would like no change to the footer but you can see where it's affecting the header select too because USA is being duplicated. Do not need that.

Comment: What do you mean by targetting both select inputs? Where are you trying to target the one in the footer? In CSS?

Comment: I'll add some pictures to help with the context.

Comment: The css is affecting both selects on the page but i only want it to affect the footer select. @lucasnadalutti

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Answered accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be more specific in your CSS selector. Instead of using:

```
.select { ... }
```

Use:

```
.region .select { ... }
```

This way you target only elements that have the `select` class AND are children of some element with the `region` class.

Comment: Okay, is there an easy way to do this inline? I know it's not best practices... if not.. that's fine.. i'll change the actual css file.

Comment: Well, you can always apply `style` directly to the element you want, but it's indeed bad practice and you'd have no need for CSS targeting if you did this.

Comment: How do i do it inline? Thanks for your answer, I'm going to test right now.

Comment: I'm really confused on how this would be accomplished inline... i know it's not good practices but ... how? Would i have to target the nth child? or is there a different way of doing it?

Comment: @thismethod What do you mean "inline"? This answer is exactly what you want. Add the string ".region " before your ".select" selector in css. And read about css selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Comment: @Kittsil, my question was simply is there a way to target children of some element inline... ie. style="stuff goes here"

Comment: @thismethod In that case, you only put the `style` property on the element you want to edit... You should include enough code to recreate the problem and a more specific question. It is okay to edit your question as answerers/commentors ask for details.